# Browser developed in delphi?

Tags: delphi, browser

Do you know a browser developed in delphi?

Comment: What programming problem are you looking to solve?

Comment: There are, of course, a lot of "browsers" developed in Delphi that use the Internet Explorer control. You can make your own in ten minutes, I bet. But I do not know of any browser made from scratch in Delphi.

Comment: Can't post an answer at the moment, but the is THTMLViewer available for free from http://pbear.com/htmlviewers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search here:

http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Good_Quality_Applications_Built_With_Delphi

http://www.embarcadero.com/rad-in-action/application-showcase

I don't understand, what you want to accomplish? Please be more explicit!